# Which accuracy (training or test) is being reported in journal articles?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I am new to neural network. When I read articles, they often say “we noted a 98% accuracy”. I carefully read the articles (see below two articles), but there is no further information whether the accuracy is referring to training or test (validation). Please let me know which accuracy is the one the authors are implying.

Grinblat, G. L., Uzal, L. C., Larese, M. G., & Granitto, P. M. (2016). Deep learning for plant identification using vein morphological patterns. Computers and Electronics in Agriculture, 127, 418-424.

Satti, V., Satya, A., & Sharma, S. (2013). An automatic leaf recognition system for plant identification using machine vision technology. International journal of engineering science and technology, 5(4), 874.

Comment: 98% accuracy on the validation set would make sense, since overtraining otherwise would give really good results.

Comment: It is generally always on the validation or testing set.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For what I read, accuracy refer to test, when you test with a large number of data, you give an opportunity to your machine learning to have a high accuracy. Of cause, the test always determine if your work gives the result expected